# Prove the following lemma concerning about quotient topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $Z$ be any topological space. Let $q: (X , \Im) \rightarrow (X \backslash \sim, \Im_q)$ be a quotient map

A mapping $f: (X \backslash \sim, \Im_q)\rightarrow Z$ is continuous iff $f \circ q :(X, \Im)\rightarrow Z$ is continuous.

If $\Im'$ is the topology on $X \backslash \sim$ satisfying the same property, then $\Im'=\Im_q$

My attempt: ($\Im' \subset \Im_q$)Take an open set $U \in Z$, since $f$ is continuous, so $f^{-1}(U) \in \Im'$. Also, $q^{-1}(f^{-1}(U)) \in \Im$, we have $q(q^{-1}(f^{-1}(U)))=f^{-1}(U) \in \Im_q$

Similarly, we will have $\Im_q \subset \Im'$.

Am I right? It seems I haven't fully utilized the condition, is it okay?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Before applying the property, you should probably specify what you're applying it *to*. We know that for any $Z$ and any map $f: X/\sim \to Z$, $f$ is continuous if and only if $f \circ q$ is continuous.

If you only apply it to one pair of $Z$ and $f$, in the continuous case, the best you can hope to show is that $\Im_q$ and $\Im'$ agree that all sets of the form $f^{-1}(U)$, for some open set $U \subseteq Z$, are open. I think in fact you have shown this.

You have not said anything about sets which are *not* of the form $f^{-1}(U)$ for some open set $U \subseteq Z$, so $\Im_q$ and $\Im'$ may disagree on those.

Comment: So if I take any open set $V \in \Im_q$, since $q$ is the quotient map, $q^{-1} (V) \in X$. Then we have $V \in \Im'$. So $\Im_q \subset \Im'$. But again, I haven't used the property and only shown one direction, where do I go wrong?